# Cordova SSL Handshake failed error on Android 7.0

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, cordova-plugins, tls1.0

I am using Cordova Android platform 5.2.2. Whenever I am performing SSL Checking on my Android N device I am facing the below error:

**CONNECTION_FAILED. Details: Handshake failed.**

From server side we are using TLS 1.0. 
And in the app SSL Certificate Checker plugin version is 5.0.0.
Cordova version is 6.3.0

I think the issue is related to Android N network security configuration changes(Because I am getting the error in Android N devices only). I have added the certificates as per the changes in Android N behavioral changes. But getting the same error.

I have updated the Cordova Android platform to 6.1.2. But getting the same error.

In Android studio after running the application, after 1 minute later the below error is raised:

**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

As the app is developed using Apache Cordova, it does not follow the Java coding. We can not apply the changes mentioned in few blogs.

Can you please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: cordova support upto API level 23 which is marshmallow os.Cordova is always one version back to the latest version of API in android.You can check the support doc here [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/).I will suggest to continue development in API 23 till further support from cordova.

Comment: If you test your backend with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/, what does the report indicate?

Also, what kind of certificate are you using (self-signed, etc.), and if not self-signed, who is the CA?

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: Dear Kerri Shots, Thanks for your reply. I have tested the backend on  (https://www.ssllabs.com). It gave the overall rating F. All Certificates are obtained from trusted certificate authority. It might be compatibility issue. the current version of TLS 1.0 is not compatible with Android N device.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the TLS from 1.0 to 2.0 resolves the issue.